# Manage only a subdomain with Google Cloud DNS

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I own a domain `example.com` and I am happy with where its DNS is hosted. I do want to delegate to Google Cloud DNS only a new subdomain `bar.example.com`.

1. Is this possible?
2. Could you point me to example code?
3. What I need to do to the DNS settings of the servers hosting `example.com`.

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it is not about programming.  In the future similar questions should be asked elsewhere.  Questions about managing your server can be asked at [sf] and questions about managing your website can be asked at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should just be able to create NS records in `example.com` called `bar` and enter the nameservers (one per entry) they gave you. That's called a "zone cut" and anybody looking up, say, `baz.bar.example.com` will be told by `example.com` to check with Cloud DNS (the same way `com` told them to check with `example.com`). When they ask Cloud DNS, they'll get the answer.

So -

1. Set up the zone `bar.example.com` on Google Cloud DNS
2. Add `NS` records at `example.com` listing the Cloud DNS nameservers given
3. ... that's it! Try it out.

Comment: OK I will try it out next. I guess the code should be the same as shown at GCDNS documentation except I use the subdomain where they use the full domain name.

Comment: On the Google side, it's just a normal zone. Use the full name when you create it, since the fact that you happen to control the parent doesn't matter on the child side (imagine the parent were 'com'). The trick here is in the parent zone, which needs to delegate authority over the subdomain to GCDNS. That's what those NS records do.

Comment: what if you have DNSSEC on foo.com? Does it affect bar.foo.com? Or do I just leave  DNSSEC off for bar.foo.com. And for the SOA, do I leave that alone correct?